# Look up table based on integer values

Tags: r, dplyr, lookup

Consider the following dataframe:

```
lookup <- 
data.frame(
level = 1:5,
points_needed = c(150, 250, 420, 580, 620)
)

lookup

  level points_needed
1     1           150
2     2           250
3     3           420
4     4           580
5     5           620
```

Now consider the following observations:

```
data <-
data.frame(
person_name = c("Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Jim", "Jim"),
match = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2),
total_points = c(100, 300, 430, 200, 600)
)

data
  person_name match total_points
1         Bob     1          100
2         Bob     2          300
3         Bob     3          430
4         Jim     1          200
5         Jim     2          600
```

I would like to create new columns in data. This column would indicate the level of the `person_name` - this changes based on the `total_points` in relation to the `lookup` table. Desired result:

```
data
  person_name match total_points level
1         Bob     1          100     0
2         Bob     2          300     2
3         Bob     3          430     3
4         Jim     1          200     1
5         Jim     2          600     5
```

I can't use a join here since there's nothing to join on. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses `findInterval`, using the actual level isn't required since it is sorted and continuous

```
data$level <- findInterval(data$total_points, lookup$points_needed)

> data
  person_name match total_points level
1         Bob     1          100     0
2         Bob     2          300     2
3         Bob     3          430     3
4         Jim     1          200     1
5         Jim     2          600     4
```

Minor note that the level for the last row appears to be 4

Adding text label to lookup table

```
lookup <- 
  data.frame(
    level = 1:5,
    points_needed = c(150, 250, 420, 580, 620),
    label = c("blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red")
  )

data$level <- findInterval(data$total_points, lookup$points_needed)
data$level2[data$level > 0] <- as.character(lookup$label[data$level])

> data
  person_name match total_points level level2
1         Bob     1          100     0   <NA>
2         Bob     2          300     2  green
3         Bob     3          430     3 yellow
4         Jim     1          200     1   blue
5         Jim     2          600     4 orange
```

Using `as.character` wouldn't be required if the labels weren't saved as factors

Comment: Let's pretend level was a string value `c("blue", "green", "yellow", "orange")`. How does the solution change?

Comment: @PhillipBlack Added string labels.  It's possible to write over the original column, but a second column was created to make it easier to confirm results.